# Explosion smoke spreads in all directions

Tags: smoke-simulation

I want to simulate a nuclear explosion using smoke/fluid simulation in blender. The problem: my smoke and fire spread in all six directions (x, -x, y, -y, z & -z) instead of forming a mushroom cloud even though I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aX9yKTzN9Y

Here's an image (I couldn't add a GIF because the file was too big):

[image]

Comment: It's going to come down to how well you matched his settings.  The best way to solve this is to go through the tutorial again step by step and make sure you've matched everything.

Comment: @MartyFouts I actually followed the tutorial quite precisely. There was some overly accurate scaling and positioning I didn't copy because I didn't want four decimal places.

Comment: Ok I just found out, this only occurs, if I use fire, not with only smoke